# have_posts order by title descending

Tags: wp-query, sort

I have custom post type 'movies' listing which i want to order by title, descending. Currently it sorts by post id. The code is:

```
<?php 
                        if( $movies->have_posts() ) : while( $movies->have_posts() ) : $movies->the_post();
                        $post_id = get_the_ID();
                        $the_movie = TMDB()->get_movie_details( $post_id );
                    ?>
```

I tried adding several things, like:

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'movies',
        'orderby' => 'title' 
    ) );  
?>
```

And also:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=ASC');?>
```

So far without succes. I am missing something. Who can help a php newbie out here?

Comment: Where is `$movies` coming from?

Comment: That is the custom taxonomy from which i want the posts to list.

Comment: No, literally where is the variable coming from? You can't just write `$movies` to query posts. You must have defined it somewhere?

Comment: $movies = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: You know what my next question is going to be, right? What’s `$args`?

Answer (score -2):

I think the part you are just missing order. Try this:

```
'post_type' => 'movies',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order'   => 'ASC',
```